# React Hooks Functional Updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React's documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) has this example:

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Why is the previous code better than:

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. In your example the other way is totally fine. However there are other cases, namely

(a) if you have an effect that sets the state:

```
  useEffect(() => {
     // ... do stuff
     setCount(count + 1);
  }, [count]); // whoops, thats kind of recursion. However if we omit it, count might change in the meantime
```

(b) if you do an asynchronous action, and the state local variable might not hold the current state value:

```
 (async function action() {
     await /*something*/;
     setCount(count + 1); // is count still up to date?
  })();
```

In these cases, using the setState callback is a way to solve the problems.